# Correct way of defining a mathematical object (linguistic)

Tags: definition

I am writing my thesis and my advisor made a correction to the sentence below:

*Transitional Rule* commonly denoted by $\phi$ is defined by **the** map $\Sigma^n \rightarrow \Sigma$.

He has changed the sentence by changing the definite article *the* to the indefinite article *a* as below:

*Transitional Rule* commonly denoted by $\phi$ is defined by **a** map $\Sigma^n \rightarrow \Sigma$.

Which of the sentences above are correct providing that $\Sigma$ is a set that is defined previously and *n* is the length of a string?

I have already asked this question in *English Stack Exchange* and I could not get any answer. They have said this a technical question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is only one map, then say "*the* map".  If there is more than one map, and your rule is defined by one of them, say "*a* map".

Comment: @GitGud, this is the first occurrence of the definition.

Comment: @Yousof If there's nothing missing in the definition, then it should be '**a** map', because there are many functions from $\Sigma ^n$ to $\Sigma$ (for $n>1$).

Comment: @GitGud, thanks for your response. The thing that I think _the_ should be used is that, although there are different functions, but **this** map defines a specific way to define the rule $\phi$.

Comment: @GEdgar may I also know your opinion about the comment above?

Comment: @Yousof But you haven't described what that map is, just that it is a map from $\Sigma^n$ to $\Sigma$.

Comment: I agree with GitGud.

Comment: @Yousof "*Binary relation on a given set* $A$ commonly denoted by $\text{whatever}$ is *the* defined by the subset $R$ of $A^2$". Do you also think 'the' is appropriate here? If so, then I suggest you just change the wording completely to something like "A *transitional rule*, commonly denoted by $\phi$, is any map from $\Sigma ^n$ to $\Sigma$".

Comment: @GitGud Thanks you clarified it for me.